# what is the difference between bisizeimage , bisize and bfsize?

Tags: bitmap

i'm new to this field ,and i get confused between some terms!

**bisizeimage**, **bisize** and **bfsize**!

please i need a simple definitions for each one, and if there is equations to calculate them ?

[bisizeimage](/questions/tagged/bisizeimage) [bisize](/questions/tagged/bisize) [bfsize](/questions/tagged/bfsize) [bitmapinfoheader](/questions/tagged/bitmapinfoheader) [bitmapfileheader](/questions/tagged/bitmapfileheader)

edited : ("answered by friend")

> biSize > The number of bytes required by the structure.
> (what is the structure exactly  ?)
>
> > The structure is the struct BITMAPINFOHEADER. That is a fixed value.
>
> biSizeImage > The size, in bytes, of the image.
> bfSize > The size, in bytes, of the bitmap file.
> (what is the difference between image & bitmap file  ?)
>
> > biSizeImage is the whole image size, bfSize is the same, but you have to add the size of the 2 header files.

Comment: what is the context? can you add a bit of more info?

Comment: @bitoiu:  It appears to be about bitmaps, specifically these: 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183376%28VS.85%29.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183374%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 12):

@Roman Abashin's answer has a slight but important error. biSize is not the combined size of both headers.

**biSize is the size of the BITMAPINFOHEADER only**. It is 40 bytes.

```
biSize = 40
```

The combined size of both headers is actually **bfOffBits** (you can think of the "Off" as referring to the offset of the actual bitmap from the beginning of the headers - remember, the bitmap comes straight after the headers).

```
bfOffBits = 54
```

Therefore all the following are correct formulas for **bfSize**:

```
bfSize = biSizeImage + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)
bfSize = biSizeImage + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + biSize
bfSize = biSizeImage + 14                       + 40
bfSize = biSizeImage + 54
bfSize = biSizeImage + bfOffbits
```

And @Roman Abashin's formula for *biSizeImage*, the size of the actual bitmap, is correct for a 24-bit bitmap.

Confusingly, biSize, bfOffBits, bfSize and biSizeImage are all in units of bytes, whereas
biWidth and biHeight are in units of **pixels**. The number of bytes per pixel is defined in the biBitCount part of the header. It is 3 bytes (or 24 bits) for a 24-bit bitmap.

Note that bfOffBits's units are in bytes and biBitCount's units are in bits.

More detail can be found on Microsoft's pages:

[Info on BITMAPFILEHEADER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-tagbitmapfileheader)

[Info on BITMAPINFOHEADER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183376(v=vs.85).aspx)

Edit: I added some annotations to the bitmap overview below to clarify things even more[image: ![layout of bitmap and headers with size information]
Edit: Changed biSizeImage + 24 (etc etc) to + 14.

Answer (score 9):

```
bfSize = biSizeImage + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)
bfSize = biSizeImage + 54               

// since BITMAPFILEHEADER = 40 and BITMAPINFOHEADER = 14 

biSizeImage = (biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) + padding) * abs(biHeight)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

One tiny typo, in @Shock451 answer.
According to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format the values of BITMAPFILEHEADER and BITMAPINFOHEADER are swapped.

there Should be:

```
// since BITMAPFILEHEADER = 14 and BITMAPINFOHEADER = 40
```

not:

```
// since BITMAPFILEHEADER = 40 and BITMAPINFOHEADER = 14
```

Answer (score 1):

**bfSize** is the full file size of the bitmap image the file size of a bitmap image is made up of two parts:

- a *header* part (with general information regarding the file = **bfOffBits**)
- and the *image part* (where the pixel information is stored = **biSizeImage**)

Therefore, we have the following structure

```
bfSize = bfOffBits + biSizeImage
```

Futhermore, **bfOffBits** (the *header* part) can be further broken up into

- a *file header* and
- an *info header* (**biSize**)

Therefore, it can be also written as

```
bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + biSizeImage
```

Since (by today's BMP definition) the size of **BITMAPFILEHEADER** is exactly 14 bytes and the size of **BITMAPINFOHEADER** is exactly 40 bytes this could also be written as

```
bfSize = 14 + 40 + biSizeImage
```

or

```
bfSize = 54 + biSizeImage
```

**However, this would be bad practice, as hardcoding 'magic numbers' is generally frowned upon.**

But let's look at **biSizeImage**. The file size of the image itself is made up, generally speaking, by the *color depth* * *width* * *height*. The color depth in a 24-bit BMP is 3 bytes per pixel (0-255 values for blue, green, red, respectively) — a so called RGB triple. Additional info for experts: the values for the three colors are saved in the order of blue, green, red — search the keyword LittleEndianness for further info on that topic. The BMP standard also adds 0's as padding if the width of the image is not divisble by 4 bytes.

Slightly confusingly, as others have pointed out, you now have to multiply the *size in pixels* with the *depth in bytes*. Therefore, we have

```
biSizeImage = (biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) + padding) * abs(biHeight)
```

which will give you the final size in bytes of the image.

So, to conclude:

- **biSizeImage** = the file size in bytes of the *image* part of a BMP
- **biSize** = the file size in bytes of the *info header* part of a BMP header
- **bfsize** = the file size in bytes of the full BMP (including both header and image itself)

[A nice overview of the structure of a BMP can be found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jAns.png)

Edit: Added correction (thanks to @MotherBrain)